# Json parsing wrong in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

Hi i have some problem parsing the json in IOS. This is the json data.

```
{
"app_info": [
    {
        "app_name": "haka",
        "sync_protocol_version": "1"
    }
],
"updates": [
    {
        "timestamp": "Sat Apr 21 13:04:08 IST 2012",
        "people": [
            {
                "personal_info": [
                    {
                        "first_name": "phlox",
                        "last_name": "",
                        "employee_id": "010",
                        "gender": "-",
                        "marital_status": "-",
                        "nationality": "Denobulan",
                        "dob": "re-23",
                        "photo": "http://c.cc/users/010/profile/image"
                    }
                ],
                "contact_details": [
                    {
                        "address": [
                            {
                                "street": "#1, this way",
                                "city": "tank",
                                "state": "sick bay",
                                "zip": "0978",
                                "country": "Enterprise"
                            }
                        ],
                        "telephone": [
                            {
                                "work": "010",
                                "mobile": "010",
                                "home": "010"
                            }
                        ],
                        "email": [
                            {
                                "work": "phlox@nx-10.ent",
                                "personal": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "emergency": [
                    {
                        "contact": [
                            {
                                "name": "-",
                                "relationship": "",
                                "telephone": [
                                    {
                                        "work": "",
                                        "home": "",
                                        "mobile": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "blood_group": ""
                    }
                ],
                "categorization": [
                    {
                        "designation": "",
                        "department": "",
                        "location": "",
                        "joining_date": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "personal_info": [
                    {
                        "first_name": "",
                        "last_name": "",
                        "employee_id": "",
                        "gender": "",
                        "marital_status": "",
                        "nationality": "",
                        "dob": "",
                        "photo": ""
                    }
                ],
                "contact_details": [
                    {
                        "address": [
                            {
                                "street": "",
                                "city": "",
                                "state": "",
                                "zip": "",
                                "country": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "telephone": [
                            {
                                "work": "",
                                "mobile": "",
                                "home": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "email": [
                            {
                                "work": "",
                                "personal": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "emergency": [
                    {
                        "contact": [
                            {
                                "name": "",
                                "relationship": "",
                                "telephone": [
                                    {
                                        "work": "",
                                        "home": "",
                                        "mobile": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "blood_group": ""
                    }
                ],
                "categorization": [
                    {
                        "designation": "",
                        "department": "",
                        "location": "",
                        "joining_date": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "messages": [
            {
                "sender": "Archer<admin@nx-10.ent>",
                "sender_role": "admin",
                "message_type": "broadcast",
                "message": "parking space up for grabs",
                "message_recipients": "all",
                "reply_permitted": "0"
            }
        ],
        "events": [
            {
                "creator": "Travis<ensign@nx-01.ent>",
                "event_title": "",
                "event_description": "",
                "event_time_start": "",
                "event_time_end": "",
                "location": "",
                "invitees": [
                    {
                        "id": "020",
                        "acceptance": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "settings": [
            {
                "sync_frequency": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

This is a valid json format. I have checked it with http://jsonlint.com/ and using http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/

see the structure of json value.According to structure the people tag should return count of 2, as it has 2 objects, but it is returning only 1 while parsing.
I am completely out of options. Please help guys.

This is the code i am using for parsing

```
NSString *textPAth = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sync" ofType:@"json"];
NSError *error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textPAth encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];    
NSArray *jsonArray = [[content JSONValue] retain]; 
NSLog(@"JSON ARRAY   %@   AND COUNT  %d",[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"updates"] valueForKey:@"people"],[[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"updates"] valueForKey:@"people"]  count]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why every dictionary is wrapped with an array, when there is only 1 entry (unnecessary), but if you want to parse it you'd want something like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[content JSONValue] retain];
NSArray *updatesArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"updates"];
NSDictionary *updatesDict = [updatesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *peopleArray = [updatesDict objectForKey:@"people"];
NSLog(@"People count: %i", [peopleArray count]);
for (NSDictionary *peopleDict in peopleArray) {
    //do something
}
```

As a side note, if this is your JSON, you'll want to remove the [arrays] for entries that are not actually arrays. While you can still parse it, it means you'll have to read the array first then get the dictionary from the objectAtIndex:0, which is totally inefficient and pointless.

Comment: +1 this should be the correct answer. One side note; when parsing JSON data and expecting an array, you may find nasty surprises, depending on the JSON rendering (usually on the server side). It is perfectly valid for such JSON renderer to actually deliver an array that contains just a single object as an object and not as an array. See for example [PHP's json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Good point. I was just giving him the quick and dirty parsing for that particular example (without error checking/defensive code).

Comment: Thanks Joel. It's working perfectly. I am completely agree with Till.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that every one of your objects is wrapped in an array and giving unexpected results?